# Android : How to set monthly and weekly repeating calendar events(for selected days) using CalendarContract?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, reminders

I am trying to set calendar events programmatically using CalendarContract. I am able to set events when I enter particular dates. What I want is, **when user selects particular days(and not enter date) of a week, I want to enter repeating events for these days every month/week from current date.** I also went through some of the [Recurrence Rules using RRULE](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/recurrence-rule-and-duration-formats/), however, I am not able to get a perfect combination. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did u found any answer for ur problem iam also having same problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can schedule events with the java class Timer. 
So ,
You define your timer with this way..

```
mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
        methodYouWantToBeCalledPeriodically();
  }
}, Date When);
```

The parameter Date is the date you want the process to be done. 
Timer provides us many scheduleAtFixedRate and schedule methods in order to use the method that fits better for you..

You can cancel your timer this way :

```
mTimer.cancel();
```

You can destroy your timer this way :

```
mTimer.cancel();
mTimer.purge();
mTimer= null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I don't think Timer actually can repeat over a period of a year. I wanted to enter the events that repeat for a year or several months. And also, I did not want to manage the repetition from app, I just wanted to enter the events in the default Android Calendar, which I am able to do now and will share my solution as an answer here!